# Is it possible to customize routing path all at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

If I set up routing like below, it creates paths automatically such as 
**community_community_topic**, 
**new_community_community_topic**, 
**edit_community_community_topic**

```
resources :communities, :path => "community" do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic"
end
```

What if I want path like this
**community_topic** instead of **community_community_topics**

How can I code my routes.rb??

Comment: Generally, you can eliminate usage of these helpers significantly. Check **[polymorphic_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_url)** to grasp the possibilities. Other helpers, like `link_to` are running their options through this method. So you can write: `link_to 'View', [@community, @topic]` or `link_to 'New', [:new, @community, :community_topic]` which are clear and don't require modifying your routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `:as`? See [Railsguides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names):

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads, :as => 'periodical_ads'
end
```